# Проблема с кэшированием в Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

Изменил меню на сайте, сбросил кэш: для администратора меню обновилось, а для гостя осталось прежним, сколько бы кэш не сбрасывал. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Кэш скидали как? Через http://joxi.ru/gmvljzOHXjQkAa ?

Comment: @Oleksandr, да.

Answer (score 1):

Помогла очистка кеша в административной панели: `Настройки > Автокеширование > Очистка файлов кеша` с выбором пункта `Меню`.